# Interpeting R significance codes for ANOVA table?

Tags: r, regression, anova

test data frame:

```
> foo
      x     y     z
1 0.191 0.324 0.620
2 0.229 0.302 0.648
3 0.191 0.351 0.626
4 0.229 0.324 0.630
5 0.152 0.374 0.656
6 0.191 0.295 0.609
7 0.229 0.267 0.665
8 0.152 0.353 0.657
9 0.152 0.355 0.655
```

Two linear models:

```
model1 <- lm(z~polym(x,y,degree = 1),data=foo)
model2 <- lm(z~polym(x,y,degree = 2),data=foo)
```

ANOVA for the two models returns:

```
> anova(model1,model2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: z ~ polym(x, y, degree = 1)
Model 2: z ~ polym(x, y, degree = 2)
  Res.Df      RSS Df Sum of Sq    F Pr(>F)  
1      6 0.002988                           
2      3 0.000169  3   0.00282 16.6  0.023 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Why the single `*`? 0.05 > 0.023 > 0.01, so shouldn't it print a `.` symbol?

Comment: The table table codes may be a bit difficult to decipher, but: 0.023 is significant at the 0.05 (\*) level, but not at the 0.01 (\*\*) level. The (.) character corresponds to the 0.1 or ten percent level.

Comment: `0 ‘***’` / `0.001 ‘**’` / `0.01 ‘*’` / `0.05 ‘.’` / `0.1 ‘ ’` / and for 1 nothing is printed. Your 0.023 falls between 0.01 and 0.05, thus it is marked with one star.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.

```
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

means:

```
annotation          p-value          significance level
   ***            [0, 0.001]                0.001
    **         (0.001, 0.01]                0.01
     *          (0.01, 0.05]                0.05
     .           (0.05, 0.1]                0.1
                    (0.1, 1]                1
```

0.023 is within `(0.01, 0.05]`, so it should be annotated by `*`.